# How can i specify a range in a http request?

Tags: java, http, outputstream

I make a http request like this:

```
Outputstream os;
os.write(("GET /Lifted-"+file+"p.dat HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
```

But in the request I would like to specify that in that file i want to start in some offset (2000 for example) and end in offset 10000. How can i make that range?
Thanks.

Comment: Range of what? what are the contents of `file`? Why are you using such a low level interface to HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the range header in your outputstream before you flush your stream. Try something as follows:

```
os.write(("GET /Lifted-"+file+"p.dat HTTP/1.0\r\n").getBytes());
os.write("Range : bytes=2000-10000\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
os.flush();
```

Maybe this could help you.

Note: Check the ietf document for Range header: [IETF Range Header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00#section-3.1)

Comment: the integers are inside the brackets too??

Comment: The range integers are not inside brackets

Comment: Let me know if you need any other clarification.

Comment: The `Accept-Ranges` header is only sent by servers, never by clients. See [RFC7233#2.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#section-2.3)